# Elliptic Curve Cryptography encryption with C#

Tags: c#, encryption, elliptic-curve

How can I use ECC in C#? I think I should use ECDiffieHellman (although I am not sure, because it's probably not an asymmetric encryption algorithm that I would like to use, but on the internet I didn't find any other recommended ones by searching for the phrase ECC), but there's no any method for encrypting and I'm not good enough at cryptography to write my own. I also don't see any NuGet packages that would allow me to encrypt with ECC. But I think it must be done somehow, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From WIKI** - Several discrete logarithm-based protocols have been adapted to elliptic curves, replacing the group Zp^x with an elliptic curve:

- The Elliptic Curve Diffie–Hellman (**ECDH**) key agreement scheme is based on the Diffie–Hellman scheme,
- The Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (**ECIES**), also known as Elliptic Curve Augmented Encryption Scheme or simply the Elliptic Curve Encryption Scheme,
- The Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (**ECDSA**) is based on the Digital Signature Algorithm,
- **The deformation scheme using Harrison's p-adic Manhattan metric**,
- The Edwards-curve Digital Signature Algorithm (**EdDSA**) is based on Schnorr signature and uses twisted Edwards curves,
- The **ECMQV** key agreement scheme is based on the MQV key agreement scheme,
- The **ECQV** implicit certificate scheme.

At the RSA Conference 2005, the National Security Agency (NSA) announced **Suite B** which exclusively uses ECC for digital signature generation and key exchange. The suite is intended to protect both classified and unclassified national security systems and information

Here is the list of C# adoptions available:

- **ECDH** (RFC6239, RFC6460 part of NSA Suite B) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng?view=net-6.0
- **ECIES** (available in OpenCrypto project) - see example of usage in Unit Test https://github.com/kazuki/opencrypto.net/blob/master/UnitTests/ECIESTest.cs
- **ECDSA** (RFC5759, RFC6460 part of NSA Suite B) there is a light-weight tool with example https://github.com/starkbank/ecdsa-dotnet
- **EdDSA** can be done with BouncyCastle https://www.scottbrady91.com/c-sharp/eddsa-for-jwt-signing-in-dotnet-core
- **ECMQV** (key agreement) can be done with BouncyCastle https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/93b32a75656955faf7996d0f3e0ed391968d2ac6/crypto/src/crypto/agreement/ECMqvBasicAgreement.cs
- **ECQV** was able to figure out Java implementation  (at least give some reference , algorithm is public) https://github.com/Trustpoint/tpm2m/tree/master/java/src/ca/trustpoint/m2m/ecqv

To summarize out of all **ECC algorithms ECDH and ECDSA are most widely used and have MS support**, the rest are available but can be more tricky.

**The deformation scheme using Harrison's p-adic Manhattan metric** - this one is poorly documented and seems to be a scientific matter (not live/widely used algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

`ECDiffieHellman` is an abstract class, so you will need to use [`ECDiffieHellmanCng`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng?view=net-6.0#examples). There is [an official example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng?view=net-6.0#examples) provided on how it works, which demonstrates message encryption and decryption.

If you need more information on implementation, please elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tool named Security-Module, which could be a Hardware-Security-Module with associated software interface, or a Software-Security-Module. on of software security modules is [PKCS#11InterOp for C#](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop). There are sample codes oin GitHub ([for RSA key generation](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/master/src/Pkcs11Interop.Tests/HighLevelAPI/_18_GenerateKeyAndKeyPairTest.cs)), for elliptic curve you must do search. however its community is not rich (you can find questions in stackoverflow with #pkcs11interop or #interop). PKCS#11 is a standard defined for security modules, and PCKS11Interop is a wrapper for its C++ library, on C#.

Usage is like this:

1. generate key pair on HSM
2. keep key-pairs names, give name to both parties
3. sign (or encrypt) a doc using public key: one of parties perform the function by calling HSM library.
4. verify (or decrypt) it using private key in other parties: other party calls HSM library and performs the function using the key name it had received from HSM.

In your system:

1. install software tools (for example SafeNet software HSM)
2. build or import a library (for example PKCS#11InterOp)